# S3 upload with PHP failed

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I don't know how to debug anymore. I use https://gist.github.com/fowkswe/3db02f1d355cab1dc300

```
if(in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
        $awsAccessKey = 'my key',
        $awsSecretKey = 'my secret key',
        $bucketName = 'my-bucket'; 
        $endpoint = 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'; 
        $s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey, false, $endpoint);
        $s3Filename = $time.baseName($fileName);

        if ($s3 -> putObject($s3->inputFile($file), $bucketName, $s3Filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {

         echo "doesn\'t goes here"

        }
        else {
            die('there was a problem');
        }
    }
```

Maybe it's my configuration issue. It's my policy of s3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any more details about the problem or failure, other than `S3 upload with PHP failed`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt not php error, I don't know why it goes to echo 'there was a problem'.